# findOne implementation changed while upgrading to mongo-java-driver 3.3.0

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, mongodb-3.3

We were previously using [**`mongo-java-driver 3.0.4`**](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/) , where in a certain block of code has this implementation -

```
DBCollection docCollection = mongoClient.getDB(dbName).getCollection(collectionName);

Map<String, Object> docMap = doc.toMap(); // where doc is the CustomDocument

DBObject currentObj = docCollection.findOne(new QueryBuilder().put("id").is(doc.getId()).get());
if(currentObj == null) {
   docCollection.insert(new BasicDBObject(docMap));
} else {
   docCollection.update(currentObj, new BasicDBObject(docMap));
}
```

What I am trying to achieve now is use [**`mongo-java-driver 3.3.0`**](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.3/) and update the code to get rid of deprecated classes and methods. What I've tried corresponding to the above piece of code is -

```
MongoCollection<CustomDocument> docCollections = mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName).getCollection(collectionName, CustomDocument.class);

Bson filter = Filters.eq("id", doc.getId()); // where doc is the CustomDocument
FindIterable<Document> documentList = docCollections.find(filter);
if (documentList == null) {
    docCollections.insertOne(doc);
} else {
    docCollections.findOneAndUpdate(filter, new BasicDBObject(docMap));
}
```

What I still find missing is the `findOne` implementation from the collection in my code and the check based actions to be performed for `insert` and `update` accordingly.

Any solution/suggestion to this are welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution playing around with the implementation in `mongo-java-driver 3.3.0`.

An easy way of performing `findOne` is now as follows -

```
MongoCollection<CustomDocument> docCollections = mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName).getCollection(collectionName, CustomDocument.class);
CustomDocument firstDocument = docCollections.find(filter).first(); //first for findOne
```

Comment: You can read it in the documentation on [the Quick Tour](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/#get-a-single-document-with-a-query-filter)

Comment: What happens when the document could not be found? Won't the first() method raise an exception?

Answer (score -1):

**`findOne()`** is also deprecated in nodeJS.

**`find().limit(1)`** is the alternative.

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOne

Comment: https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.3/ List<DBObject> obj = collection.find(query).skip(1000).limit(100).toArray();